# SQL query selecting different row result in JSON_MODIFY because of In operator provided value

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have two sql tables name as
`commonformsschema` columns are `SchemaId,SchemaName,Tenant,Schema`

and `ApplicationRoles` columns are `SchemaId,RoleName,create,read,update,delete`.

And things is like One SchemaId can we exists in Multiple RoleName.
So when i try to execute the following query in JSON_Modify different roleName result getting appended.i have tried but not found anything how to solve this.

**here is the query:**

```
select *
from
(
    select fs1.SchemaId,
     ----------------------------------------------not working as expected
           JSON_MODIFY(
                          fs1.[Schema],
                          ISNULL(
                                    N'$.roles[' +
                                    (
                                        SELECT j.[key]
                                        FROM OPENJSON(fs1.[Schema], '$.roles') j
                                        WHERE JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.role') = ar1.rolename
                                    ) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 + N']',
                                    N'append $.roles'
                                ),
                          JSON_QUERY(
                          (
                              SELECT ar1.RoleName AS [role],
                                     ar1.[create] AS [permissions.create],
                                     ar1.[read] AS [permissions.read],
                                     ar1.[update] AS [permissions.update],
                                     ar1.[delete] AS [permissions.delete]
                              FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
                          )
                                    )
                      ) AS [Schema],
-----------------------------------------------------------------
           
           row_number() over (partition by fs1.schemaName
                              order by case
                                           when fs1.tenant = 'ALL' then
                                               2
                                           else
                                               1
                                       end,
                                       fs1.tenant
                             ) as seqnum
    from ApplicationRoles ar1
        join commonformsschema fs1
            on ar1.SchemaId = fs1.SchemaId
    where fs1.Tenant in ( 'constructiontest', 'All' )
          and ar1.RoleName in ( 'Construction Manager Admin', 'Project Manager Admin', 'Read' )
) t3
where seqnum = 1
```

for more details please see the [db fiddler](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a28a54aa4c2c17cd31eadd547d7187d6)

**Current Result:**
only single rolename object `Construction Manager Admin` getting append and not updating existing `Read` rolename object in schema column roles property.

```
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "role": "Default",
      "permissions": {
        "read": false,
        "create": false,
        "update": false,
        "delete": false
      }
    },
    {
      "role": "Read",
      "permissions": {
        "read": false,
        "create": false,
        "update": false,
        "delete": false
      }
    },
    {
      "role": "Construction Manager Admin",
      "permissions": {
        "create": false,
        "read": false,
        "update": false,
        "delete": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected Result:**
Both rolename `Construction Manager Admin`,`Project Manager Admin` add and `Read` rolename object should be updated in schema column roles property.

```
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "role": "Default",
      "permissions": {
        "read": false,
        "create": false,
        "update": false,
        "delete": false
      }
    },
    {
      "role": "Read",
      "permissions": {
        "read": true,
        "create": false,
        "update": false,
        "delete": false
      }
    },
    {
      "role": "Construction Manager Admin",
      "permissions": {
        "create": false,
        "read": false,
        "update": false,
        "delete": false
      }
    },
    {
      "role": "Project Manager Admin",
      "permissions": {
        "create": true,
        "read": true,
        "update": true,
        "delete": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Please any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample input, expected results and current results would help. You should use `CROSS APPLY` more, it helps to separate out calculation of values and make the query more readable

Comment: @Charlieface i have added current and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot expect `JSON_MODIFY` to run multiple times recursively using different rows. Each execution will run once independently per row, so each object is being applied to the original JSON separately.**

If you remove `where seqnum = 1` you will see what I mean.

---

**Instead, I think you should just rebuild the whole JSON object from scratch.**

This is made more complicated by the fact that you don't want to delete anything from the JSON that isn't in your existing rows

- We begin by filtering `commonformsschema` to only the rows you want, taking `All` into account.
- Then, within an `APPLY`, we take the rows we need from `ApplicationRoles`....
- ... and crack open the existing JSON into separate rows
- ... and `FULL JOIN` them together (we need `FULL` because `Default` doesn't exist in the table)
- We construct JSON out of that using explicit path syntax, and a root `roles` object.
- I've put in an `ORDER BY` to keep the ordering of the original JSON, but that is not necessary if you don't care.
- The `APPLY` subquery can also be done as a correlated subquery directly in the `SELECT`, as you have done.

```sql
SELECT
    fs1.SchemaId,
    j.newJson
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        row_number() over (partition by fs1.schemaName
                   order by case when fs1.tenant = 'ALL'
                              then 2 else 1 end,
                            fs1.tenant
                             ) as seqnum
    FROM commonformsschema fs1
    WHERE fs1.Tenant IN ( 'constructiontest', 'All' )
) fs1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        ISNULL(ar1.rolename, j2.role) role,
        ISNULL(ar1.[create], j2.[create]) [permissions.create],
        ISNULL(ar1.[read], j2.[read]) [permissions.read],
        ISNULL(ar1.[update], j2.[update]) [permissions.update],
        ISNULL(ar1.[delete], j2.[delete]) [permissions.delete]
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM ApplicationRoles ar1
        WHERE ar1.SchemaId = fs1.SchemaId
          AND ar1.RoleName IN (
            'Construction Manager Admin',
            'Project Manager Admin',
            'Read' )
    ) ar1
    FULL JOIN OPENJSON (fs1.[Schema], '$.roles') j1
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (j1.value)
            WITH (
              [role] nvarchar(100),
              [create] bit '$.permissions.create',
              [read] bit '$.permissions.read',
              [update] bit '$.permissions.update',
              [delete] bit '$.permissions.delete'
            ) j2
      ON j2.[role] = ar1.rolename
    WHERE (fs1.ModifiedDateTime > '2021-07-12 04:25:57.0000000' OR
           ar1.ModifiedDateTime > '2021-07-12 04:25:57.0000000')
    ORDER BY ISNULL(j1.[key], '9999')
    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, ROOT ('roles')
) j(newJson)
WHERE fs1.seqnum = 1
  AND j.newJson IS NOT NULL;
```

[db<>fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b0136ee841a04c17956d3062bee0b926)

Comment: Thanks,i think answer look correct for me..onces i need to test multiple scenario with actual db tables and records.

Comment: if you don't mind i have one doubt like how to access ```ar1``` other column outside like ```WHERE fs1.seqnum = 1 and (fs1.ModifiedDateTime > '2021-07-12 04:25:57.0000000' or 
ar1.ModifiedDateTime > '2021-07-12 04:25:57.0000000')``` to check ```ModifiedDateTime``` on both table.if any table has modification i have to access those record.

Comment: OK put that in for you

Comment: It's not working..in result fetching prior modified row as well...but if i m using like this working as expected...```......WHERE fs1.seqnum = 1 

and fs1.schemaid in (select distinct cfs1.SchemaId from CommonFormsSchema  cfs1 inner join ApplicationRoles ars1
 on cfs1.schemaid= ars1.schemaid where (cfs1.ModifiedDateTime > '2021-07-26 10:22:27.7133333' or 
ars1.ModifiedDateTime > '2021-07-26 10:22:27.7133333' ))```....but i want to remove this extra query thing how?

Comment: I suggest you create another question for this. Please supply a full [mcve], a db<>fiddle would be best