# How to merge/join result from two tables in single row based on match id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL Server tables `commonformsschema` and `ApplicationRoles`, and a common `SchemaId` column in both tables.

In one `schemaId` column is unique and in another table the `schemaid` column with multiple times. Now using join I have to merge both tables in single row based on `schemaid` column.

Here is the query which i am trying

```
WITH fschema2 AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             fs1.SchemaId, fs1.[Schema],
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fs1.schemaName
                                ORDER BY CASE WHEN fs1.tenant = 'ALL' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, fs1.tenant) AS seqnum 
         FROM
             commonformsschema fs1 
         WHERE 
             fs1.Tenant IN ('constructiontest', 'All')) t3
    WHERE 
        seqnum = 1
)
SELECT 
    json_modify(fs2.[Schema],
    ISNULL(N'$.roles[' + j.[key] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 + N']', N'append $.roles'), 
    json_query((SELECT 
                    ar1.rolename AS [role],
                    ar1.[create] AS [permissions.create],
                    ar1.[read]   AS [permissions.read],
                    ar1.[update] AS [permissions.update],
                    ar1.[delete] AS [permissions.delete]
                 FOR JSON PATH, without_array_wrapper))
     ) AS [Schema] FROM fschema2 fs2
JOIN
    ApplicationRoles ar1 ON ar1.schemaId = fs2.schemaid
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP (1) j.[key]
     FROM OPENJSON(fs2.[Schema], '$.roles') j
     WHERE JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.role') = ar1.rolename) j;
```

For more detail about input and table detail please see the [db fiddler](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3164c39de677c10c26d5f32a320a7cab).

Current result (3 rows):

**Schema**

```
{
  "roles": [
     {
      "role": "Read",
      "permissions": {
        "read": true,
        "create": false,
        "update": false,
        "delete": false
      }
    }
  ,{"role":"Construction Manager Admin","permissions":{"create":false,"read":false,"update":false,"delete":false}}]
}
{
  "roles": [
     {
      "role": "Read",
      "permissions": {
        "read": true,
        "create": false,
        "update": false,
        "delete": false
      }
    }
  ,{"role":"Project Manager Admin","permissions":{"create":true,"read":true,"update":true,"delete":true}}]
}
{
  "roles": [
     {"role":"Read","permissions":{"create":true,"read":false,"update":false,"delete":false}}
  ]
}
```

Expected result (1 row):

Schema

```
{
  "roles": [
     {"role":"Read","permissions":{"create":true,"read":false,"update":false,"delete":false}},
     {"role":"Project Manager Admin","permissions":{"create":true,"read":true,"update":true,"delete":true}},
     {"role":"Construction Manager Admin","permissions":{"create":false,"read":false,"update":false,"delete":false}}
  ]
}
```

For any other details, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query selecting different row result in JSON\_MODIFY because of In operator provided value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68501146/sql-query-selecting-different-row-result-in-json-modify-because-of-in-operator-p) Stop reposting the same question

Comment: Yes, thanks ......