# Update/replace array with JSON_MODIFY

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have json object in table column that contains array type key `roles`.
I am trying to replace `roles` value but it's instead replace existing roles, adding new inside roles.
here is the [db fiddler](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=99c9599d3cc8dc9e7e7afdbeb048bc17).

**current result:**

```
{
  "roles": {"roles":[{....}]}
 }
```

**expected result:**

```
{
  "roles":[{....}]
}
```

Any help is appriciated.
thanks.

Comment: Don't use `JSON_MODIFY(fs1.[Schema],'$.roles',JSON_QUERY(j.newJson)) as [Schema]`. Just use `JSON_QUERY(j.newJson) as [Schema]`

Comment: @GGG i have to append roles property in  ```schema``` object,..it's not single roles property that schema object contains.

Answer (score 0):

Query look correct,But passing object `{roles:[]}` as input to `JSON_QUERY(j.newJson)`  instead of  array `[]` value.

Either you can modify input or extarct array value from input to get expected result by using `JSON_QUERY` path.

**Before**

```
JSON_MODIFY(fs1.[Schema],'$.roles',JSON_QUERY(j.newJson)) as [Schema]
```

**After adding `JSON_QUERY`  path**

```
JSON_MODIFY(fs1.[Schema],'$.roles',JSON_QUERY(j.newJson,'$.roles')) as [Schema]
```

for more details see ths docs [JSON_QUERY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @r08 If it answered your question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**The point of [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68514433/14868997) was to fully rebuild the JSON, which is why I added `, ROOT ('roles')`.**

So you don't need to use `JSON_MODIFY`, just replace the entire column.

Alternatively, if for example you have other parts to the JSON, you can remove `, ROOT ('roles')` and leave `JSON_MODIFY` in.